# Plotly: Add specific values to default ticks

Tags: python, plotly

I want to simply add specific values to the default tick values as created by plotly:

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.arange(1, 6)
y = x ** 2
df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[x, y], columns=['x', 'y'])

fig = px.line(df, x='x', y='y')
```

Let's say now that I want an additional tick on the x axis at 5.5. Thus, it would be best if I could do something like:

```
fig.layout.xaxis.add_ticks([5.5])
```

Alternatively, I thought about getting the default ticks in a list `defaultticks` and add the new ones in there resulting in a list `newticks`. As far as I know, one would need to set `fig.update_xaxes(tickmode='array', tickvals=newticks)`.  But, I don't know any function to get the default ticks, as `fig.layout.xaxis.tickvals=None` before assigning `tickvals` manually.

Edit 1:
It should also work in-between the min/max data point, i.e. I would like to be able to do `fig.layout.xaxis.add_ticks([4.5, 5.5])`

Comment: My fuzzy memory is that I am aware that if you set up a new tick list, it will be valid. What if I don't get the current values, but set a new one? Or, if you want to rewrite it directly, you can also do the following. `fig=px.line(...);fig.data[0]['x'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5.5];fig.data[0]['y'] = [ 1,  4,  9, 16, 25, None]`

Comment: To get the data structure of the plotly drawing, you can use the following code. `fig.data`

Comment: That won't work for ticks in-between min/max of data points.

Comment: Present the intended output. I could not imagine the intended output from your comment.

Comment: State what you don't understand. The question is clearly formulated.